Trouble Deploying Application with Docker Compose: Address Already in Use for HTTPS
I am trying to deploy my application using Docker Compose, but I encounter the following error:
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:8080: address already in use.
When I configure my application to use only HTTP, it works without any issues. However, when I switch to HTTPS, I receive this error. I have removed HTTP from the configuration, but the same error persists for HTTPS:
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://[::]:8081: address already in use.
I have searched for numerous solutions but nothing seems to work. Here are the steps I have tried:

Removing the "binding" in Docker Compose, changing the port mapping from 8081:8081 to 8081
Checking if the port is occupied by any process and terminating it (none are occupying it)
Testing on both Alpine Linux and Windows Docker Desktop, but I still get the same error

Here are some relevant parts of my code, docker-compose.yml and launshSettings.json :
Program.cs
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
{
    var configuration = context.Configuration;

    // Configure HTTP endpoint
    options.ListenAnyIP(8080, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
    });

    // Configure HTTPS endpoint
    options.ListenAnyIP(8081, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
        {
            httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
                configuration["Kestrel:Endpoints:Https:Certificate:Path"],
                configuration["Kestrel:Endpoints:Https:Certificate:Password"]);
        });
    });
});

docker-composer.yml:
myApp:
  container_name: appdocker
  image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myApp
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: myApp/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080"
    - "8081"
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:8081;http://+:8080
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=1234@999-
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/root/.aspnet/https/certDocker.pfx
  volumes:
    - ./aspnet/https/certDocker.pfx:/root/.aspnet/https/certDocker.pfx
  depends_on:
    - myAppdb
  networks:
    - myNet

launshSettings.json:
  "Container (Dockerfile)": {
    "commandName": "Docker",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
      "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
    },
    "publishAllPorts": true,
    "useSSL": true
  }
}

Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081



FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

FROM build AS publish
COPY ./out /app/publish


#Build img
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir -p /root/.aspnet/https

COPY ./aspnet/https/certDocker.pfx /root/.aspnet/https/certDocker.pfx

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]



Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve this? Thank you!
